# How to use formgroup in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using angular2 in my project,i have a service which returns this JSON Object :

> items={"departure":"New York","arrival":"California","stations":[{"station":"toto"},{"station":"titi"},{"station":"tata"}]}

i tried to populate this JSON object in the UI like this picture shows:
[here's what the result looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyBgl.png)

heres the code :

```
<div class="panel-body panelcolor">

<div *ngIf="items?.departure">
    <span>{{items.departure}}</span> --> 
    <span *ngIf="items.stations.length > 0">
        {{items.stations[0].station}}
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="items.stations.length === 0">
        {{items.arrival}}
    </span>

    <div class="input-group spinner">
        <input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
            <button (click)="spinnerPriceUp()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
            <button (click)="spinnerPriceDown()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    

<div *ngFor="let item of items.stations; let i=index, let last = last">

    <div *ngIf="!last">
        <span>{{item.station}}</span> --> <span *ngIf="items.stations[i+1]">{{items.stations[i+1].station}}</span>
        <div class="input-group spinner">
            <input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control">
            <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
                <button (click)="spinnerPriceUp()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
                <button (click)="spinnerPriceDown()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div *ngIf="items?.arrival && items?.stations.length > 0">
    <span>{{items.stations[items.stations.length-1].station}}</span> --> <span>{{items.arrival}}</span>
    <div class="input-group spinner">
        <input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
            <button (click)="spinnerPriceUp()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
            <button (click)="spinnerPriceDown()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button style="margin-left: 479px;"> Submit </button>
```

my problem is when i tried clic (up or down) the spinner to change the value of the textBox, all the textBoxes change its value.can anyone help please to fix this problem ?

Comment: It's because you've got the same value for all of your `formControlName` attributes (`formControlName="price"`).  That means they are all bound to the same underlying variable.  Change them to be bound to different variables....

Comment: so this is it, how can i do that moreover, i have to retrieve each value of the textBox